# How do you/Can you convert text to image (raw data)?

Tags: image, text, converters

Not an image of text, but raw image data.

Such as in Audacity where random text input generates white noise when you use "Import Raw Data" for example.

Comment: its really hard understanding your question.

Comment: Please give an example as your question is unintellligible.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I changed the title now. Is it still unintellligible? I am asking how, or if it even is possible to, convert text to image. I already gave an example which is "Import Raw Data" in audacity, except in audacity you convert text (or other data) to audio, not to an image.

Comment: Nope, still don't get it. Let's say I start with some text, let's say "Freddy Frog", what should I end up with? A JPEG image of those 2 words? A raw something? What should I be able to do with the result?

Comment: @MarkSetchell A gibberish image I suppose. I don't know how any of this works but I just think its interesting. If I type "Freddy Frog" a few thousand times in a txt file and import it "Raw" to Audacity it gives me a loud beeping noise. An equivalent output but an image instead.